# FileNotFoundException EACCES (Permission denied) on contentResolver.openFileDescriptor (Android)

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to load a bitmap using the [exact sample code from developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#bitmap)

```
val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor
val image: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
```

but I'm still getting a:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The URI looks like this:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_SOMETHING.jpg
```

And I've aquired the runtime permissions

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
```

Obviously I'm still missing something (for scoped storage?) but I can't figure out what. Any ideas?

Target SDK is 30 and test device is API 29 (Android 10).

Comment: use file picker.

Comment: I get the URI from a different process and do not have control over it so can't use a file picker :(

Comment: Try adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` inside the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: It does actually work but it's not the long term solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the URI with a `file://` prefix did not seem to work. I eventually had to create a URI with a `content://` prefix for it to work:

```
content://media/external/images/media/889
```

I had to go (back) to the area the file(s) were queried and add a `MediaStore.Images.Media._ID` field to the query:

```
val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                arrayOf(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID // Important line!
                ), null, null, null)
```

Then read and "store" the ID from the cursor when moving through the results

```
val id = cursor.getLong(0)
```

and use it later on for creating the URI:

```
val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor
val image: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
```

Not sure if this is actually the right solution but it seemed to work for me.